# Unable to view image on my website when importing the image src from python list

Tags: python, image, flask

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = '{{ game["TEAM_1_IMAGE"] }}') }}" width="30" height="30">
```

I am using the above to display an image for which the image src is stored in a python list, but no image is being displayed. Please help! Thanks!

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static' , filename = 'game["TEAM_1_IMAGE"]') }}" width="30" height="30">
```

This also does not work and I just don't know why

Comment: 'game' is an object of the list I am iterating btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without quotes round that, assuming `game['TEAM_1_IMAGE']` is available in the template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=game['TEAM_1_IMAGE']) }}" width="30" height="30" />
```

---

The mistake in your first codeblock is trying to nest Jinja expressions.  Avoid doing this.

In the second codeblock, consider that `filename` is an argument to the `url_for` function.  The same rules apply within a template expression as if you were passing an argument to a function in pure python:

```
url_for('static', filename=game["TEAM_1_IMAGE"]) # Works
```

You can see that this passes the *value of* `game["TEAM_1_IMAGE"]` as the `filename` argument.

The mistake was trying to pass a string as the argument.

```
filename='game["TEAM_1_IMAGE"]'
```

Comment: It works! Can you explain why this works and not my code though? I can't seem to understand it.